# Website doesn't show up correctly in IE. Fine in mozilla, chrome,safari etc

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

So basically when I viewed [my site](http://www.stepanandreasian.com/) in IE everything looked wrong. You cant scroll and it seems like its stuck. If you notice the project page compared to chrome for example looks really large and wont let you scroll. Contact page also looks out of place a little. Also the blog in mostly all the browsers except chrome doesn't show up correctly. I decided to use object tags instead of an iframe to include the blog into the html webpage.

---

Thanks guys,

I managed to fix it for IE to be viewable but now the plugin PrettyPhoto found here: http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/

doesn't open up correctly in project page unless I view IE in compatibility view.

The validation errors keep mentioning 
 tags but I dont know if that would fix it.

Comment: can you please add a link to your site? I can't see any in the message

Comment: Welcome to web design. Meet IE.

Comment: [link](http://www.stepanandreasian.com) Here is the link, sorry I thought it would post the link above..

Comment: In the world of browsers, mentioning a brand without a version number is quite useless... IE6? IE9? Something in between? IE5.5 in MacOS 9? ;-)

Comment: It looks same in IE9 as what it looks in chrome

Comment: all versions of IE don't seem compatible with the coding

Comment: @Maysam ..Ive tried IE9 on a windows 7 machine and it looked a little better but same problems..weird

Answer (score 3):

first of all IE doesn't support lots of standards, so you should almost always optimize for this browser (do additional hacks, etc)

1.
but, about this website, I think using frames is a bad idea here (using frames is usually a bad idea)
I'd make a sidemenu as a div with fixed positioning using CSS, I think you'll have no problem to scroll even in the IE then

2.
sometimes when you really don't want how to optimize your web for IE, developers usually use some kind of rules just for IE (personally I never use them)
http://css-tricks.com/132-how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

3.
I recently found out that there is a [project](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) which is making IE to behave more like a standard browser, so you dont' have to think about IE very much
you just include some JS files and lots of things are easier

to sum it up... there are ways how to optimize for IE (or other browsers), in this case I'd use the left sidebar as fixed using CSS

wish you good luck, you're gonna need it :)

PS. and last advise - keep your site valid

Comment: Just to add: IE<9, at least, poorly supports the object tag. Inept at best IE is the worst browser on the planet.

Answer (score 1):

It might be related to your site's [validation errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.stepanandreasian.com/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).  (It doesn't look right in Safari on an iPad either.)