# Why does my site look different on every browser?

Tags: html, css

Please check out this snippet of my site.

http://jsfiddle.net/TmnPV/

The logo is made up of the 'circle1' and other div tags in the same html sections. It doesn't show up on jsfiddle either and it looks different on every browser.

On chrome = shows all
On firefox = no logo shows and bottom text under input field is larger
On safari = no logo shows

What can I do?

Comment: check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131101/website-doesnt-show-up-correctly-in-ie-fine-in-mozilla-chrome-safari-etc/7131171#7131171)

Comment: Welcome to the exciting world of web development :)

Answer (score 2):

This is called, umm... , welcome to wild wild world of web. Every browser vendor parses html/css/javascript differently. Some are lenient, some are strict. (Chrome Vs. Opera). Some have different Box model, some have standard operational behavior, some tend to do their own thing.(Opera Vs. IE6)
Answer to different renderings : You have to hunt down each and every little quirk. One by one.
Welcome.

Comment: Ah i look forward to it... here is my site weezy.co.uk 
its perfect in chrome but everything else doesn't run it all

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to adjust your styles for older browsers if you plan on doing alot of css3 transforms.

IE 6, 7, and 8 just don't have the ability to read those styles.

Even on Firefox, depending on the version, you'll run into various spacing issues since the rendering engine is different than Chrome (and Safari).

For using html5 and css3 in older IEs you can (sparingly) use polyfills, which duplicate the effect using javascript. You can see a list of available polyfills here:
https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

Quirksmode is a great resource for checking compatibility: http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html

I would highly recommend the *Firebug* add-on for Firefox to see where the extra spacing, etc is happening.

When you run into a specific issue with a specific browser that you can't figure out post a question here. It's much easier to help with one bug than just general browser problems.

Answer (score 0):

That's mostly because you are using code to work with one browser. Different browser uses different code renderer. It's hard to make everything look the same, even tho Internet explorer is the worst, other browsers have different features. Opera has most of the HTML5 form features, that no other browser supports so far, but Chrome and Firefox supports the most of the HTML5 attributes. Hope this helps understand the reason why.

Comment: So is there a site that can help me for example make the css shapes i made compatible for internet explorer/safari/firefox. Also part of the site that isn't showing is just text... why isn't that showing? its just text..

Comment: No there is no easy way, you have to learn a lot to be able to position, display, sort your CSS the way it will look *almost* the same in every browser. Also a good start for it would be including [Eric Meyer Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or using [Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) as a site design start.